# Python: Split string into two columns by more than one seperator

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am importing data from a csv file, I want to split the column 'topThemes' into an array/dataframe with two columns.
 
In the first column I want to have the name of the theme (e.g. Biology), in the second column I want its associated score (e.g. 62).
 
When I import the column it is stored in this format:

```
Biology: 62\n
Economics: 12\n
Physics: 4\n
Chemistry: 8\n
and so on.
```

My current code and the error is shown below.

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'myfilelocation')

split = [line.split(': ') for line in df['topThemes'].split('\n')]
```

Error:

```
AttributeError("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'")
```

CSV file being imported:

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E00CibEuLgmCTnLO6qoqf2sQnbqvRp0JBtjxZ6q1SCY/edit?usp=sharing)

How I want it to look:

[Ideal format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1cxI.jpg)

Thanks for any help / responses.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Copying was disabled on your shared sheet. Why not simply put the raw CSV in the question itself and make it easy for others to help? Better yet, provide code that creates the desired df, assuming the file is fine. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it's my first time on the site i'll see if I can do that now, thanks.                        edit: I am not sure how to add a raw CSV to the post but I allowed the file to be copied and downloaded, thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming the `split()` that's causing the error is the second one, and so `df['topThemes']` must be returning a `Series`.  `Series` is an iterable, so what happens if you just get rid of the second `split()`? (Disclaimer, I've never used pandas, and barely used python.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the delimiter to use with `sep` and the column names with `names` of the `read_csv()` function:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'myfilelocation', sep=':', names=['topThemes', 'score'])
```

Documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Oh, I see your source CSV file now...
There's probably a cleaner way to do this in less steps, but I think this produces your requested output:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'myfilelocation', usecols=['topThemes'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data['topThemes'].str.split('\n').values.tolist()).stack().to_frame(name='raw')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df[['topTheme', 'score']] = data['raw'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(":")))
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: please give a brief explantion :)